# Calculating an average temperature using Python and weather API

Tags: python, weather-api

I am trying to calculate an average 10-day temperature by finding the average daily temperature between high and low, and then dividing the average in total time frame by 10. I am using the weather APi, running on the command line with a postcode. Currently I have invalid syntax errors but can't figure out what's wrong- perhaps I am missing a bracket or using an incorrect one.
Error is: print city ['city']
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Any help would be appreciated.

```
from weather import Weather
import sys

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    weather = Weather ()
    location = weather.lookup_by_location((sys.argv[1]))
    forecast = location.forecast()
    city = location.location()


    average = 0

for f in location.forecast():
    averageTotal = f(f[int('high')] + f[int('low')] / 2 

   print city ['city']
   print "10 day average temperature:" + str(averageTotal / 10)


else:
    print "You must supply a postcode to get the atmospheric pressure."
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback of your error.  And while you are at it, first read it carefully.  In most cases, this will solve your problem.

Comment: In the future, providing the actual error would be useful. That said, I think your issue is the different indentation levels of `averageTotal = ...` and `print city...`

Comment: @JCVanHamme That, and the fact that he is missing a closing parenthesis on this line: `averageTotal = f(f[int('high')] + f[int('low')] / 2`. But your right. He needs to include his full error message.

Comment: int('high') is incorrect, int takes a string that can be converted to a number, eg. int('123'). Also, 'f(f' is probably wrong as well. But, to help you further, include a sample of the data for city and location.forecast().

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to python! Your code can be fixed via static code analyzers like `pylint`. Try to use it. Also the average that you are calculating for a 10 day period was overwriting itself when you assign a new value to `averageTotal` in the for loop. Here's a better way of writing it.

```
import sys
from weather import Weather


if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    weather = Weather()
    location = weather.lookup_by_location((sys.argv[1]))
    forecast = location.forecast()
    city = location.location()
    average = 0

print city['city']
averageTotal = 0
for f in location.forecast():
    averageTotal += (int(f['high']) + int(f['low']))

print "10 day average temperature:" + str(averageTotal / 10)
```

*P.S.* Don't use `for-else` if you are new to python. It will just confuse you. If you would like to read what it does then please refer to [this](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html).

Answer (score 0):

Well your error tells you that `print city ['city']` is invalid, it's quite explicit.

Are you trying to print the value of the key `'city'` in the dict `city`?
Then you need to remove the white space before `['city']`.

Otherwise, what is this line actually supposed to do?

Comment: I am a beginner, it's not always obvious what everything does

Comment: That's why I'm asking you to explain what the line should do with your words :)